# Calculate Adjacent Fields Issues

Tags: arcgis-desktop, adjacency

I am trying to run the Calculate Adjacent Fields ToolBox on one of my Shapefiles, but the process is taking hours to run, and I have yet to complete the process. My table is 18,000 rows, and so far the most I've gotten through was 2,000 after 5 hours.  I tried creating and index on the field I want to run the Calculate Adjacent Fields on, (MN_80).   But that does not seem to improve performance.

Has anyone run into this issue before, and what were some solutions you found to speed up the process?

Comment: Does your Shapefile have an updated Spatial Index?

Comment: That was it, took more like 15 min.  Thanks for the suggestion.